# How do I ask a company to reschedule an interview to a more convenient date?

Tags: interviewing, scheduling

I have been invited to interview at the office of the company I have applied to on a Wednesday morning. Having already resigned from my current company I don't have any work to do during my last month but since I am still being paid so I show up to the office still. I have another interview on Thursday afternoon, so would it be reasonable to ask them to reschedule it to Thursday morning so that I would only have to take one day off?

Comment: Just ask them politely...

Comment: "Would it be possible to reschedule this to Thursday morning?" You're overthinking this.

Comment: Is there any other possible answer other than "Just Ask Nicely"?

Comment: This question is not company specific.  It's convoluted, a bit obvious maybe.  However the essence of it is how to deal with requesting interview schedule changes and about transition activities between jobs.  Certainly good answers could benefit others in a generalized way. @dukeling

Answer (score 4):

> I have another interview on Thursday afternoon, so would it be
>   reasonable to ask them to reschedule it to Thursday morning so that I
>   would only have to take one day off?

Yes, that's very reasonable.

Just indicate that you are busy Thursday afternoon and ask if Thursday morning would be acceptable instead.

Most employers will understand and work with you to find a mutually acceptable time and day.